# CC2541 PCB Antenna check

Tags: pcb-antenna

I'm designing a 4 layer CC2541 board. I'm using recommended balun from TI. I'm also using the same layer stack as in CC2541 Keyfob reference design.

I'm following exact antenna dimensions mentioned by TI. I'm using MIFA type pcb antenna. 
One part of pcb antenna is connected to GND and feed line is connected to Balun's antenna pin. How can I mention this two things in Altium?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "mention in Altium"? Are you looking for a DRC rule to check the antenna design or just a way to annotate on the PCB without affecting the design?

Comment: For MIFA antenna, there are two connection. Feed point and GND connection. These two are connected together. So I assign feed point to Antenna Net connection and GND point to GND plane using via. But Altium is giving me error for short circuit constraint.

Comment: Can you just ignore the error then?

Comment: I don't use altium, but I found this [document](http://wiki.altium.com/download/attachments/25079430/NetTies-and-How-to-Use-Them.pdf) which may be helpful

Comment: A net tie is what I use for PCB antennas. It allows different nets to be connected together in one location.

Comment: Thanks guys, Sounds like the solution I want. I'll look into it. And anyway, This error can be ignored as far as one know whats he doing.

Comment: Seems like this type of net ties are being used for RF transmission. http://altiumpcbdesigner.blogspot.ca/2012/05/net-ties-how-to.html